# Lua script (help needed)

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

i have a little script which works, but i wanted to add something which doesnt work out. I would be really happy if i could get any help
That is my script:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true); 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
         repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
            Sleep(2.0)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
   end
end
```

and that is what i tried:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
         if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
            repeat
               MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
               Sleep(2.0)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
      end
   end
end
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you tried, what you're attempting to accomplish, and in what way it doesn't work?  Looking at the second code snippet, it looks like you're trying to attach an `until` clause to an `if`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: `IsMouseButtonPressed(2)`  Probably you want RMB? 2=middle, 3=right.

Answer (score 2):

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   Sleep(5)
   if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
      while IsMouseButtonPressed(1) and IsMouseButtonPressed(2) do
         MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
         Sleep(2)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: That works perfect for me, thank you very much for your quick help :)